# Stored Procedure that will raise if there's no data in SSRS report

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm looking for a way to create a stored procedure that will raise if there's no data from a report that I have in SSRS. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by raise? do you mean raise error?

Comment: Stored procedures can't monitor reports 24/7.   They can't trigger themselves at all.   You would have to create a job or something similar.

Comment: @TabAlleman - I think he wants the report to run an SP if there is no data. Maybe the SP is to populate the data.

Comment: @HannoverFist what's SP? Sorry for the questions but I'm pretty new to SSRS/SQL.

Comment: @Machzy - **S**tored **P**rocedure. i.e. sp_addlogin

Comment: @KamranFarzami Yes, I mean raise error.

Answer (score 1):

For your dataset query, put the results in a temp table.

```
SELECT ...
INTO #TEMP_DATA 
FROM ....
```

Put the count of the table in a variable.

```
DECLARE @COUNT AS INTEGER = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TEMP_DATA)
```

If variable = 0 then run your SP.

```
IF @COUNT = 0 THEN
    SP_MY_STORED_PROC
```

SELECT your results for the report query.

```
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_DATA
```

**OR** Rerun your query to populate the table with refreshed data first (if that's what the SP does).

```
IF @COUNT = 0 THEN
SELECT ...
INTO #TEMP_DATA 
FROM ....
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly. If you don't have a data for your query in SSRS. You can use 'NoRowsMessage' option in your Tablix properties.